# AS3: Upload image to Facebook - Graph API

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an app where users can upload webcam pictures they take at an event. I can post plain text to Facebook, but the problem is that I can't upload the pictures. I use the following code:

**Get bitmap and encode to bytearray as jpg**

```
public function set source(bmp:Bitmap):void {
    var encoder:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder(75);

    _bitmap = encoder.encode(bmp.bitmapData);
    img.source = bmp;
}
```

**Post to facebook**

```
private function postFB(e:Event=null):void {
    var _params:Object = new Object();

    _params.uid = Facebook.getAuthResponse().uid;
    _params.access_token = Facebook.getAuthResponse().accessToken;
    _params.message = "I was at the Thanksgiving Day Event! #GobbleGobble";
    _params.fileName = "gobble.jpg";
    _params.image = _bitmap;

    Facebook.api("/me/feed", postComplete, _params, "POST");
}
```

The above code doesn't work. If I place `_params.image = _bitmap;` in comment, The message is posted to my wall. I use GraphAPI_Web_1_8_1.swc. I use the following permissions:

> {perms:"read_stream, publish_actions, user_photos, photo_upload"};

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Or how I should upload images using GraphAPI? :) It's not a matter of upload-time, because I have been waiting for over an hour now and it still hasn't uploaded.

Comment: i don´t think photo_upload exists...for posting photos, all you need is publish_actions.

Comment: I found the list of permissions on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/permissions. I figured I'd give it a try :)

Comment: fql is deprecated, and that permission list is VERY old ;)

Comment: Hmm.. It has only been three years since I've done some decent programming using Facebook, but it seems the entire Facebook-api I knew is deprecated! :p

Comment: well, 3 years is a lifetime on the internet ;)

Comment: That is very much the truth!

Comment: If it is still relevant for you, for me it worked with the "photos" api call, like: `Facebook.api("/me/photos", ...` , and with **no** `message` property under `_params` object..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by saving the image to my server using a php-script and then using the direct link to the image to post to facebook.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upload image ByteArray as multipart/form-data request. Here is my code, that works, using [this tool](https://github.com/markpasc/MultipartURLLoader):

```
public function postImage(bmp:Bitmap, message:String):void {
        var byteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 
        bmp.bitmapData.encode(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.width, bmp.height), new JPEGEncoderOptions(90), byteArray);

        var loader:MultipartURLLoader = new MultipartURLLoader();
        loader.addVariable("message", message); // message is required by Facebook
        loader.addVariable("access_token", Globals.accessToken);
        loader.addFile(byteArray, "image.jpg");


        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
        loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
        loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onError);

        var url:String = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me/photos";
        loader.load(url);
}
```